# Core data returns empty strings and content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to populate my tableView with storaged data in CoreData. When tableView is trying to populate it's cells the name and also date of fields in cell are empty. Size of NSMutableArray created from NSArray like so:

```
-(void)copyArrayToTableMutableArray:(NSArray *)coreDataArray
{
    if(self.fetchedRecordsArray != nil)
    {

        modelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:coreDataArray];
        NSLog(@"%d", [modelArray count]);
    }
}
```

shows that there are for example 3 items. When program goes to populate section it creates cell but they are empty. This is code for populating:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    CustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if([modelArray count] > 0)
    {

            Kwejki *tmpModel = [modelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Here it is empty NULL
            NSLog(@"%@",[tmpModel name]);
            cell.titleOfCell.text = [tmpModel name];
            cell.dateOfAddedCell.text = [[tmpModel date] stringValue];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

And I'm saving new item to the CoreData like this:

```
-(void)addNewPosition:(ScrollViewViewController *)ScrollController recentlyDownloadedItem:(KwejkModel *)modelTmp
{
    NSLog(@"DODAJE NOWA POZYCJE");
    NSLog(@"%@",[modelTmp description]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [modelArray count]);
    //[self.tableView reloadData];


    Kwejki * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kwejki" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"%@", [modelTmp getNameOfItem]);

    newEntry.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[modelTmp getNameOfItem]];
    newEntry.rating = [modelTmp getRateOfPosition];
    newEntry.urlMain = [modelTmp getUrlAdress];
    newEntry.contentUrl = [modelTmp getContentUrl];
    newEntry.coverUrl = [modelTmp getCoverImage];
    newEntry.date = [modelTmp getDateOfItem];



    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"UDALO SIE!!!");
    }


    [modelArray insertObject:newEntry atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I've searched around but haven't founded why it is empty. Do you know why?

Comment: can you paste output of  `modelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:coreDataArray];
        NSLog(@"%d", [modelArray count]);`

Comment: Do your `newEntry` attributes get populated properly in `addNewPosition`? Have you tried logging them after being set?

Comment: Yes, I've logged them and the attributes are set up. @codester NSLog shows number of items = 5. Always one more than before.

Comment: Is tmpModel not `nil`?

Comment: The tmpModel is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Core Data populated table views you should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Then you can retrieve your object reliably with

```
Kwejki *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

*The following is not recommended:*
If you really want to stick to your ill-advised array solution, it would help to make sure you have a property or instance variable. Clearly, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` your array has already been deallocated.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *modelArray;
```

Comment: I have variable NSMutable array in this class and now I've changed it for your proposal and it also does not help. When I save item it has all Strings etc. but when I'm trying to load it again they are empty.

Comment: But after executing fetch as above in code I got 5 items but the has no Strings. Where has been made a mistake?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Thank you for the interest. I've solved the problem creating everythink from the scratches. I don't know where was the mistake but it is working now. Forgive me if it wasn't interested post.

Comment: OK, If you don't mind, please accept this answer to show other users the preferred way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are using UIManagedDocuments so you may need to put a [self.managedObjectContext save] in add new position after you populate your newentry fields.  I know you shouldn't have to do this that the data is there in memory, but if you are using different contexts in your insert and in your fetches, you wouldn't see the data until a save was done on it.  It may not help, but give it a try.